# How to print the folowing to console in scheme r5rs language

Tags: scheme, r5rs

```
(define x '())
x
```

in repl console gives => `'()`

```
(define x '())
(display x)
```

gives => `()` but I want to print it like `'()`

How can make *display* print `'()` rather than `()` ?

I need this because my function is logging the error incase of bad inputs provided by user and i want to print `'()` input as `'()` only, kinda like how scheme does when you run the following:

```
(define x '())
(cdr x)
```

gives =>

```
mcdr: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: '() (Note the ')
```

Comment: The printed representation of an empty list as `'()` is a Racketism; I don't remember ever seeing a Scheme implementation do this, even in error messages. This is one way that writing Scheme code using one of Racket's RnRS langs is not quite like using dedicated Scheme implementations. You might be able to put a single quote in by hand when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
(define x '())
(define y '(1 . 2))
x ; ==> ()
y ; ==> (1 . 2)
```

Thus evaluating `x` in a Scheme REPL will show `()` since when you evaluate `'()` it evaluates to the thing without the first `'`.

## Racket oddeties

In Racket they have configurable how the REPL is supposed to print values in the REPL / interactive window. In `#lang racket` when you use `display` you'll see what the value **really is**

```
(display x) ; prints ()
(display y) ; prints (1 . 2)
```

However in `$lang r5rs` the default REPL with default settings output setting is `print`:

```
x ; ==> '()
y ; ==> (mcons 1 2)
```

With `constructor` as output style:

```
x ; ==> empty
y ; ==> (cons 1 2)
```

With `quasiquote` as output style:

```
x ; ==> `()
y ; ==> `(1 . 2)
```

All of the above doesn't really print the value. It prints an expression in the chosen style that, when evaluated, will become the same value. `'()`, `empty`, and  `` `() `` all evaluate to `()` so all of them are printed for the value you get when evaluating `'()`

The only sensible choice is to use `write` as output style. This will print the real value in the REPL in the same manner as all other scheme implementations:

```
x ; ==> ()
y ; ==> (1 . 2)
```